# JavaScript click event not running on button added after DOM loaded when using document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pretty common problem which I have solved hundreds of times before but right now I am missing something or it isn't working.

I made a simple mockup to demonstrate the issue on JSFIddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/L9axv9cc/

Basically I have some HTML for a Button that is created and inserted into the page DOM after the page DOM has already loaded.

I then create a `CLICK EVENT` on that new button that is generated after DOM load.

In the past I have always been able to use `$('document')` to make click events work on items that are added after the DOM load.

For some reason this time it does not work on this example....

```
$('document').on('click', '#btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1', function(e) {
    alert('We just clicked a button that was created after the DOM had loaded and a new click event was attached to it after the page was fully loaded and working already!');
});
```

---

The example is below as well.  When you click the button it generates and injects my new Button into the DOM with the ID `#btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1`

Next if you then click that new button, it does nothing!

So my Click vent is not being attached to the item created after DOM load.

Please help?

---

**Full code for the JSFiddle example mockup**

```js
// click button to generate the button with ID #btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1 that is to be created after the DOM has loaded.  
$('#create-new-button-from-this-button-click').click(function(){
    
    // HTML for our new button that we are to create
 var newButtonHtml = '<input type="submit" value="Reject & Move to Backing Status Board" id="btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1" class="btn btn-primary">';
    
    // Insert HTML for the new button into this #fake-modal DIV
    $('#fake-modal').html(newButtonHtml);
    
    
    // Now attempt to attach a new click event onto the button that we just injected into the page DOM...
    // I used  $('document') on the click event below as that is how I generally handle
    // getting EVENTS to work on items that are added to the DOM after the DOM has been
    // built/loaded already. 
    $('document').on('click', '#btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1', function(e) {
        // run code when this button clicked on
        // this click event does not work!
        alert('We just clicked a button that was created after the DOM had loaded and a new click event was attached to it after the page was fully loaded and working already!');
    });
    
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="create-new-button-from-this-button-click" value="Insert new button HTML into DOM">
    
    
<div id="fake-modal">Fake Modal HTML</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont use a string selector, `document` is an object and should be accessed as such.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1',
```

```js
// click button to generate the button with ID #btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1 that is to be created after the DOM has loaded.  
$('#create-new-button-from-this-button-click').click(function(){
    
    // HTML for our new button that we are to create
 var newButtonHtml = '<input type="submit" value="Reject & Move to Backing Status Board" id="btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1" class="btn btn-primary">';
    
    // Insert HTML for the new button into this #fake-modal DIV
    $('#fake-modal').html(newButtonHtml);
    
    
    // Now attempt to attach a new click event onto the button that we just injected into the page DOM...
    // I used  $('document') on the click event below as that is how I generally handle
    // getting EVENTS to work on items that are added to the DOM after the DOM has been
    // built/loaded already. 
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-reject-move-to-DraftingStage1', function(e) {
        // run code when this button clicked on
        // this click event does not work!
        alert('We just clicked a button that was created after the DOM had loaded and a new click event was attached to it after the page was fully loaded and working already!');
    });
    
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="create-new-button-from-this-button-click" value="Insert new button HTML into DOM">
    
    
<div id="fake-modal">Fake Modal HTML</div>
```

Comment: Also - you don't need event delegation here... your handler is being bound *after* the HTML is written...

Comment: @tymeJV, right, good point. But I think its harmless either way. Perhaps the user will add more elements in the future in his real code

Comment: IF so, Rather Use `$('#fake-modal')` instead of `$(document)` !

Answer (score 1):

document is an object and not a tag/selector, you should use it as follows:

```
$(document) //Remove the quotes around document.
```